# pytest finding tests outside of specified directory when importing function whose begins with test

Tags: python, testing, pytest

With the following file configuration:

```py
### contents of my_module.py
def testtime_func(path):
  pass

### contents of my_test.py
from my_module import testtime_func

def test():
  testtime_func(1)
  assert True
```

The command `pytest my_test.py` fails with:

```
============================================================= test session starts =============================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/zaccharie/workspace/tests/pytest_failing
plugins: typeguard-2.7.1
collected 2 items                                                                                                                             

my_test.py E.                                                                                                                           [100%]

=================================================================== ERRORS ====================================================================
_______________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of testtime_func _______________________________________________________
file /home/zaccharie/workspace/tests/pytest_failing/my_module.py, line 1
  def testtime_func(path):
E       fixture 'path' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

/home/zaccharie/workspace/tests/pytest_failing/my_module.py:1
=========================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================
ERROR my_test.py::testtime_func
========================================================= 1 passed, 1 error in 0.01s ==========================================================
```

I don't understand why `pytest` looks for test function outside the specified path (but that are imported).

I tried belt and suspenders by also configuring the [testpaths](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-testpaths), but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pytest first finds the test files specified by paths etc., then imports them and looks for any function or class matching the [configured naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions).

It does not inspect the test cases it finds for where they come from; if you import something into the namespace of a module, Pytest thinks it's fine there.

Your options are:

- rename that `test...` function as you import it:
  `from my_module import testtime_func as foo_testtime_func`
- import the whole module and call `my_module.testtime_func`:
  `import my_module`
- [change the naming convention](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-python_functions) (if you really need to)

Comment: The first option is what would work best for me. Tested it and it works like a charm.